# Was there ever a resolution to the 2002 series Speed Racer X?

Tags: story-identification, anime, manga, speed-racer

**Speed Racer X** was an update of the wildly popular 1960s Japanese anime, **Speed Racer,** [which, in itself, had a 1993 American update by DIC]. However, it was less episodic, with the 13 episode series having one over arching story [The World Grand Prix] with the side story of the Racer family uncovering/ coming to terms with the mystery of the death of Eldest son, Rex, who in reality  [in all versions] was the secret agent/ wild card Racer X.

I'm unsure if there was a manga or continuation of the series [it ran for 1 season on the Nick block *Slam!* and had no second season]. The final episode had Speed qualify to go to the finals of the World Grand Prix, but nothing came of that race, or revealing Racer X's identity.

Does anyone know if this series was continued somehow, either via a next season, movie or manga?

And if so, can you please post a link there to?

Comment: IMDB shows only the one series, with seven episodes. https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0338661/ The only new addition to the franchise is _Speed Racer: The Next Generation_.

Comment: I guess it depends on which "resolution" you meant, considering the original Japanese was cut on the 34th episode (out of planned 52), but the English dubbed version was further cut on the 13th episode due to the lawsuit...

Comment: @AndrewT. whaaaat? There were further episodes?! I knew it! Can you link to a place where they can be watched with subs?

Comment: Funimation holds the right and the only way to watch this is from [Speed Racer: Collector's Edition](https://www.amazon.com/Speed-Racer-Collectors-Corinne-Orr/dp/B074VLD7VF) which includes the whole 34 subbed episodes of *Speed Racer X* (listed as *Mach Go Go Go: Restart*)... that aside, I don't know if there are any legal sites streaming it.

Comment: @AndrewT. Damn! Well...thank you nonetheless, friend; that counts as a solid answer. You should put it in answer form here.